# How to change background color of button onClick in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, background-color

There is more than one button using the map function and display it.
Want to change the Background color of a button that I click. And others want it as it is.
And again when I click on another button then only change the BG color of that button only.
There are two files. One component id define button component using map function and another one is button component.
**Main Component**

```
 state = {
        categories: [],
        selectedCategory: null,
        value: 'test',
        clicked1: false,
    }
categorySelectedHandler = (id ,e) => {
        this.setState({ selectedCategory: id });
    }

const categoriesName = this.state.categories.map((category ,index) => {
            // console.log("The current iteration is: " + index);
                let visible_in_pricing_page = category.visible_in_pricing_page
                    
                    if (visible_in_pricing_page) {
                        return <CategoryBtn
                            index = {index}
                            name={category.title}
                            key={category.id}
                            selectedId = {this.state.selectedCategory}
                            clicked={() => this.categorySelectedHandler(category.id)}
                />
            }
        });
```

**CategoryBtn Component -**

```
import React, { Component  } from 'react';
import classes from './price-category-btn.css';

const CategoryBtn = props  => {
    
        return (
            <div style={{display:"inline"}} >
                <a>
                    <button 
                    className= { classes.category_btn } 
                    onClick={props.clicked}>{props.name}</button></a>
            </div>
        )
    }

export default CategoryBtn;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the `selectedId` prop to the CategoryBtn component, you can make use of it or you can pass in a boolean already

```
const categoriesName = this.state.categories.map((category, index) => {
  // console.log("The current iteration is: " + index);
  let visible_in_pricing_page = category.visible_in_pricing_page

  if (visible_in_pricing_page) {
    return <CategoryBtn
    index = {
      index
    }
    name = {
      category.title
    }
    key = {
      category.id
    }
    {/** indicate this is the selected button  */}
    selected = {this.state.selectedCategory === category.id} 
    clicked = {
      () => this.categorySelectedHandler(category.id)
    }
    />
  }
});
```

In the categoryBtn component return the button with a dynamic class

```
<button 
    {/** use props.selected to dynamically set the class */}
    className={`${classes.category_btn} ${props.selected}` ? classes.selectedCss : ''}
    onClick={props.clicked}
 >
   {props.name}
 </button>
```

And in your CSS module, you can have the class for the background-colour

```
.selectedCss
{ background-color: lightblue;}
```

Comment: I try the same code that you answer above but result is by default BG color of btn displaying green. And I want defaut class classes.category_btn and after click changes to classes.selectedCss  @Ashu

Comment: Modify the ternary then according to your needs : className={props.selected ? classes.selectedCss : classes.category_btn }

Answer (score 1):

For those that don't want to deal with onClick, simply override the buttons default scss calls. So, for example if you wanted to change all primary buttons when active/clicked it would look something like this:

```
index.css

.btn-primary:active {
  --bs-btn-active-bg:#ff79c6;
  --bs-btn-active-border-color: #ff79c6;
  --bs-btn-active-color: #44475a;
}
```